# Autofixure sublist example

Tags: autofixture

I have two class with one-to-many relationship

```cs
class Book
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int AuthorId {get;set;}
    public string BookName {get;set;}
}

class Author
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string AuthorName {get;set;}
    public List<Book> Books {get;set;}
}
```

I want to use AutoFixture to build the list of authors, But I cannot set book.AuthorId related with author.Id
can anyone advise?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default AutoFixture does not know how to correlate types, especially if there is no explicit relationship between them.

The simplest solution would be to create the Author instance first and then using a builder set the `AuthorId` property.

```cs
var fixture = new Fixture();
var author = fixture.Create<Author>();

var book = fixture.Build<Book>()
.With(x => x.AuthorId, author.Id)
.Create();
```

This however is very verbose and not very helpful when you have to create multiple instances.
A more generic way to instruct AutoFixture, to automatically link the two entities would be to effectively "freeze" a collection of `Authors` and make each created `Book` get the `AuthorId` from an existing (frozen) `Author`.

You can find the implementation for `RandomFromFixedSequence<T>` from the following example in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/aivascu/ddd6c942f75ea0f71c9268c55517059b).

```cs
[Fact]
public void BooksHaveValidAuthorIds()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    fixture.Customize(new RandomFromFixedSequence<Author>());

    fixture.Customize<Book>(c => c
        .With<string, Author>(x => x.AuthorId, v => v.Id));

    var authorIds = fixture.CreateMany<Author>().Select(x => x.Id);
    var book = fixture.Create<Book>();

    authorIds.Should().Contain(book.AuthorId);
}
```

The solution is heavily inspired from Enrico Campidoglio's blog post [General-purpose customizations with AutoFixture](https://megakemp.com/2013/04/16/general-purpose-customizations-with-autofixture/). Check it out to see how I ended up with that customization implementation.